# Question about Kinetic Energy and Force acting on a body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

Below is the graph of a body that rests on a friction-less flat surface. On this body force F is applied and it's value is being depicted in the graph below. We can see that the body moves from point O to $x_1$, $x_2$ etc.

[image]

I want to ask something that i can't understand. Why does kinetic energy increase from point O to $x_1$? If someone could explain i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the *Work-Energy Theorem*. The work done on an object by an external force $\vec{F}$ is
$$W=\vec{F}\cdot \Delta \vec{x},$$
where $\Delta \vec{x}$ is the displacement. The Work-Energy theorem says that the work is equal to the change in kinetic energy:
$$\Delta K=W.$$
So the reason that the kinetic energy is changing for the particle is that $\vec{F}\cdot \Delta \vec{x}$ is positive for the region $(0,x_1)$. Although the force might be getting smaller, it is still positive (if we read that graph as "The force in x-direction" and the object is moving along the x-direction).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, F is also getting smaller (and from what i see faster than the change in x). How is KE accumulated and thus increasing? This is my primary concern. Also, what's happening with velocity? Is it increasing? Because if KE is increasing then velocity also should increase, right?

Comment: Take a simple example - I push with 20 N for 5 cm, 10 N for 5 cm, then 5 N for 5 cm (decreasing force over distance right?). During the first interval my kinetic energy increases by 20*.05=1 J. During the second interval, my kinetic energy increases by 10*0.05= 0.5 J, and during the third it increases by 5*0.5=0.25 J. It's always increasing - just by less and less as you travel forward. Since the kinetic energy is increasing, so is the velocity.

Comment: Now i remembered what i was thinking. As x increases in your example KE decreases 0.25<0.5<1J. And this was my concern. But we count it individually i guess, as chunks of (kinetic) energy being added to the total energy of the body.

Comment: It's not counting it individually, it's that Work is a *change* in kinetic energy. It changes by a lot (1 J) then a smaller amount (0.5 J) but the change is always positive, so it's still getting bigger. If the change was negative (like -0.5 J or something), then the object would slow down.

Comment: Yes, i understand now. Just to be sure.. from $x_1$ to $x_2$ the body moves steadily, since net force is 0. So the KE from $x_1$ to $x_2$ neither decrease, nor increase. It remains constant to what it was right before it reached $x_1$. Right?

Comment: Yup that's totally right - from $x_1$ to $x_2$ there is no force on the object, so the velocity is constant, which means the KE is constant. When it reaches $x_2$ the kinetic energy begins to increase again.

Answer (score 1):

> How is KE accumulated and thus increasing? This is my primary concern. Also, what's happening with velocity? Is it increasing? Because if KE is increasing then velocity also should increase, right?

Between $x=0$ and $x=x_1$, a net force, say $F$, is acting on the body. With Newton's Second Law we get:

$$F=ma,$$

with $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$ the acceleration and $v$ the velocity.

So:

$$F=m\frac{dv}{dt}$$

$$dv=\frac{F}{m}dt$$

$$v=\frac1m \int_0^tFdt$$

Here $F$ is not a constant (in fact it's decreasing) in time but it's always positive and that means **that up to** $x=x_1$, $v$ (and kinetic energy $\frac{mv^2}{2}$) keeps increasing.

Comment: Well, the only trouble here is we don't know F as a function of time, only as a function of position. You should probably replace $dt=(dt/dx)dx$ and integrate with respect to x.

Comment: Actually, we know that $F=F_1(1-x/x_1)$. Also: $Fdx=mvdv$, So $\frac{mv^2}{2}=\frac{F_1x_1}{2}$.

Comment: right that works fine, I'm just saying you can't take that integral in the last line because F is an unknown function of $t$. Your comment is exactly what I meant.